# Is there a readymade R function to round a range to the nearest superset defined by integers?

Tags: r, range, rounding

I would like to round the min and max of a vector to the nearest integer, so that the new set defined by the two values is an actual superset of the previous data.

For instance, for a vector between 1.1 and 2.9, round(range()) returns 1 and 3, which is the desirable outcome:

```
x <- seq(1.1, 2.9, 0.1)
oldrange_x <- range(x)
newrange_x <- round(oldrange_x)
newrange_x
```

On the other hand, for 1.8 and 2.9 round(range()) returns 2 and 3, which is not a superset of the initial vector:

```
y <- seq(1.8, 2.9, 0.1)
oldrange_y <- range(y)
newrange_y <- round(oldrange_y)
newrange_y
```

and leads me to use a combination of floor() and ceiling()

```
newrange_y2 <- c(floor(min(oldrange_y)), ceiling(max(oldrange_y)))
newrange_y2
```

Would there be a readymade function doing that -essentially a roundrange() function- in order to avoid the ugly solution and make the code a bit more readable?

Comment: Ready made function? I know of nothing in base R that does that; frankly, I've never wanted to do exactly that, so I haven't looked ... and admittedly, I'm still learning base R functions that have exists for years (decades). You said that your 1.8-2.9 example is wrong, please demonstrate what you think is right (it is not obvious to me, there are several possibilities).

Comment: your `c(floor(min(oldrange_y)), ceiling(max(oldrange_y)))` looks like a perfectly adequate solution.  Why not just use that?  You could put it into a function of your own in less time than it takes to write a question here.

Comment: @r2evans The desire output would be 1 and 3, as the nearest integers defining a set that contains all the values of the initial vector, i.e., y ⊆ [1, 3]. The round(range()) solution returns 2 and 3, a range that doesn't include all initial values. The third method in the opening post works, I was just wondering if there was an already available one-liner solution.

Comment: Okay, needed verifying, thanks. I really don't think something preexisting is going to do that, since it's not patently obvious to `floor` one and `ceiling` the other, and `round` is clearly not suited for this task. I suggest the `superset` function provided by @BillO'Brien is probably pretty good, though I'd add (for completeness) an `na.rm=` argument to the function, passing as-is through to `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of floor and ceiling is perfectly fine, not ugly at all. Here's how you would wrap it in a function.

```
superset <- function(x){
    c(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)))} 

superset(seq(1.8, 2.9, 0.1))
> [1] 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you edit your answer and use seq() instead of c() in the last line to make it technically correct?